# Nhibernate Query and OrderBy cause multiple join on the same tables

Tags: nhibernate, sql-order-by, outer-join

The two core entities in the model are:

- Account
- Registration

Here is the fluentNH mapping between Account and Registration:

```
.Override<Account>(m =>
 {
   m.References(x =>
     x.Registration).Cascade.All().Not.Nullable().Unique(); 
     // unidirectional one-to-one association, unique will not allow multiple nulls
 }
```

We have a query to find the top 10 (accountid, registrationid) that
match a certain filter criteria (expression on account) and are
ordered by  two fields on the registration

Example:

```
 public class AccountRegistrationId
{
  public Guid AccountId { get; set; }
  public Guid RegistrationId { get; set; }
}
```

THE QUERY:

The query:

```
(from r in _session.Query<Account>() select r)
.OrderBy(a => a.Registration.PatientVisit)
.OrderBy(a => a.Registration.AccountNumber)
.Where(a=>a.Registration.Mrn == "Mrn 1234")
.Select(a =>  new AccountRegistrationId{     AccountId = a.Id,
                                                                RegistrationId = a.Registration.Id
                                                          }
).ToArray();
```

the resulting sql  has 4 outer joins between account and
registration:

```
select   TOP ( 10 /* @p0 */ ) account0_.Id    as col_0_0_,
                     registrati3_.Id as col_1_0_
from     [Account] account0_
         left outer join [Registration] registrati1_
           on account0_.Registration_id = registrati1_.Id
         left outer join [Registration] registrati2_
           on account0_.Registration_id = registrati2_.Id
         left outer join [Registration] registrati3_
           on account0_.Registration_id = registrati3_.Id,
         [Registration] registrati4_
```

The problem: multiple left outer joining with Registration table

- One join for the projection
- One join for the Where Criteria
- Two joins for OrderBy criteria (one for each order by)

Is there anyway to get rid of these multiple joins on registration ?

Comment: Please use {} for code formatting in order for your question to be readable...

Comment: @Cristian Boanu: The `{}` button isn't the only way to format code here. Select and Ctrl+K or a four space indent also work. I got it.

Comment: Did you find any answer here?